# Incrementing VBA For loop through command button

Tags: vba, for-loop, increment, activexobject

Good day!

I am currently having a slight issue with a command button, which, I would like to be able to do the following: format a specific row to a certain row height, add thick borders to a certain number of cells in this same row and counting and adding the number of rows thus produced to the initial number in the file. Basically, the button should enable the user of the spread sheet to add a new row with specific formatting into which the user will input data and keep track of the number of rows added.

My current code stands as is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub NewLineRedButton_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long

    For y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(16.3) To y + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(16, 3) = y + 1
        For i = 20 To i + y Step 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Rows(i).RowHeight = 45
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

At the moment the code executes only for two rows below and stops. I am not quite sure, why...?

Comment: maybe because some of the values are hardcoded?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by hardcoded. I have next to no programming knowledge, I am surprisingly ignorant, but willing to learn.

Comment: @BOB so what is special about `Cells(16, 3)`? Aka `C16`?

Comment: It displays the number of rows on this sheet. By rows here, I mean the number which have been filled in by the machine operator. There are other rows of headers and fluff on top of the rows being filled in, these don't count. The initial value is set at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a for loop like this

```
For y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(16.3) To y + 1
```

is the same as writing it like this

```
For y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(16.3) To 1
```

I'm guessing the value in the cell is zero so it will execute the loop for 0 and 1 - i.e. the two times you are seeing.

You need something like

```
lEndRow = lStartRow + (lRowCount - 1)
For y = lStartRow to  lEndRow
```

Comment: I am not sure of the logic behind your code.
 Here is what I grasp:
 I should create a variable which is the end row (lEndRow).
 I should create a variable which is the start row (lStartRow).
 Then using the Row.Count function make the loop cycle in function of how many rows there are...?

Comment: I don't think I need the start row really, as all I need to know is where the last row is on the sheet so I can plus a new row just beneath it. Thanks, for helping!

Comment: If all you need is the last row on the sheet then store this value. When you insert a new row add one to the value. This will save you having to worry about the number of rows etc.

Comment: Not quite, I need both the last row so that I may add another row beneath it and the number of rows added + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have this going fine now. Just can't get it to do all the columns with the right borders... I am not sure how to to call them while using the cells(#, #) notation and I can't see how to use the Range(''Z#,Z#'') notation with my i variable being a Long...

Anyways: here's the result so far:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub NewLineRedButton_Click()

        Dim i As Long
        Dim y As Long
        Dim RowEnd As Long


        RowEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For y = 19 To RowEnd
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(16, 3) = y - 17 ' First row which is already on the sheet is on row 19, first row appearing by button clicking is on row 20 and the program is counting the header hence the y - 17 for the value of the number of rows.
        For i = 19 To RowEnd + 1 Step 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Rows(i).RowHeight = 45
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.Weight = xlMedium

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help and ideas, finally wiggled around and found other resources from the leads given here.